# Offline-Open street maps on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, openstreetmap

I'm planning to implement an offline map solution for windows phone using open street maps. To achieve this, would I need to download complete OSM database first and than use it? Or is possible to fetch it on-demand and store it locally?

If OSM is not the best solution what else could be used to have an offline maps application? Offline data would be required only for about 3-5 cities, not more than that.